# How does casting to "signed int" and back to "signed short" work for values larger than 32,767?

Tags: c++, c, variables, types, casting

**Code:**

```
typedef signed   short  SIGNED_SHORT;   //16 bit
typedef signed   int    SIGNED_INT;     //32 bit


SIGNED_SHORT x;

x = (SIGNED_SHORT)(SIGNED_INT) 45512; //or any value over 32,767
```

**Here is what I know:**

> Signed 16 bits:
>   Signed: From −32,768 to 32,767
>   Unsigned: From 0 to 65,535

Don't expect 45512 to fit into `x` as `x` is declared a 16 bit signed integer.

**How and what does the double casting above do?**

Thank You!

Comment: @Aesthete: my bad, typo, I mean any value over 32,767

Comment: Short isn't guarrenteed to be 16 bits. You should use int16_t

Comment: @matzahboy: you're wrong. however, `int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Comment: @matzahboy: on this system it is.

Comment: Short is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits. It isn't guaranteed to be exactly 16 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef signed   short  SIGNED_SHORT;   //16 bit
typedef signed   int    SIGNED_INT;     //32 bit
```

These `typedef`s are not particularly useful.  A typedef does nothing more than provide a new name for an existing type.  Type `signed short` already has a perfectly good name: "`signed short`"; calling it `SIGNED_SHORT` as well doesn't buy you anything.  (It would make sense if it abstracted away some information about the type, or if the type were likely to change -- but using the name `SIGNED_SHORT` for a type other than `signed short` would be *extremely* confusing.)

Note also that `short` and `int` are both guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits wide, and `int` is at least as wide as `short`, but different sizes are possible. For example, a compiler could make both `short` and `int` 16 bits -- or 64 bits for that matter. But I'll assume the sizes for your compiler are as you state.

In addition, `signed short` and `short` are names for the same type, as are `signed int` and `int`.

```
SIGNED_SHORT x;

x = (SIGNED_SHORT)(SIGNED_INT) 45512; //or any value over 32,767
```

A cast specifies a conversion to a specified type.  Two casts specify two such conversions.  The value `45512` is converted to `signed int`, and then to `signed short`.

The constant `45512` is already of type `int` (another name for `signed int`), so the innermost cast is fairly pointless.  (Note that if `int` is only 16 bits, then `45512` will be of type `long`.)

When you assign a value of one numeric type to an object of another numeric type, the value is implicitly converted to the object's type, so the outermost cast is also redundant.

So the above code snippet is exactly equivalent to:

```
short x = 45512;
```

Given the ranges of `int` and `short` on your system, the mathematical value `45512` cannot be represented in type `short`.  The language rules state that the result of such a conversion is implementation-defined, which means that it's up to each implementation to determine what the result is, and it must document that choice, but different implementations can do it differently.  (Actually that's not *quite* the whole story; the 1999 ISO C standard added permission for such a conversion to raise an implementation-defined signal.  I don't know of any compiler that does this.)

The most common semantics for this kind of conversion is that the result gets the low-order bits of the source value.  This will *probably* result in the value `-20024` being assigned to `x`.  But you shouldn't depend on that if you want your program to be maximally portable.

Answer (score 5):

When you cast twice, the casts are applied in sequence.

```
int a = 45512;
int b = (int) a;
short x = (short) b;
```

Since 45512 does not fit in a `short` on most (but not all!) platforms, the cast overflows on those platforms.  This will either raise an implementation-defined signal or result in an implementation-defined value.

In practice, many platforms define the result as the truncated value, which is `-20024` in this case.  However, there are platforms which raise a signal, which will probably terminate your program if uncaught.

**Citation:** n1525 §6.3.1.3

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: It's not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eq: you're wrong. the answer is correct. *WAIT*, there should be a "on those platforms" qualification, so you're right. sorry. i'll fix it.

Comment: **EDIT**: added important "on some platforms" qualification (weasel snippet). it's important to understand that the same source code has UB on some platforms but is well-defined on most platforms. it all depends on the ranges involved.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It's not "some" platforms, but "those" platforms -- the same platforms where 45512 does not fit in a short.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, but there seems to be no floating point types in this conversion.

Comment: 6.3.1.3 says: When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type -- the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised

Comment: @eq: this seems to be the night of hasty confuzion... i think you meant to address that comment to Dietrich. however, my own correction was a bit incorrect, AND SO ON.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: ah, sorry; I thought you added the citation as well.

Comment: @Dietrich: the appropriate quote for C++11 is §4.7/3: "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined."

Comment: @eq-: I keep on remembering this bit incorrectly, and it doesn't help that §3.4.3 says "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow."

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I've erred the same way myself a couple of times. Conversion and overflow are two different beasts.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I think you meant §3.18/3 of the C standard (not §3.4.3)

Comment: If anyone's not yet confused, just watch the next episode. @Dietrich: nice if you would add the citation for C++ (given above). I'll keep my fingers away from this now... ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't have the C++ standard, and I don't cite standards that I don't have access to.  Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 4):

The double casting is equivalent to:

```
short x = static_cast<short>(static_cast<int>(45512));
```

which is equivalent to:

```
short x = 45512;
```

which will likely wrap around so `x` equals `-20024`, but technically it's implementation defined behavior if a short has a maximum value less than 45512 on your platform. The literal `45512` is of type `int`.

Comment: It's not UB ... check the standard.

Comment: The question is tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++]; `static_cast` is specific to C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume it does two type conversions (although `signed int` and `int` are only separated once in the C standard, IIRC).

If SIGNED_SHORT is too small to handle 45512, the result is either implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. (In C++ only the former applies.)

Comment: typo!! sorry, I got so caught up in the question, 45,512

Comment: But even if it didn't fit, I would [naively] expect the same result (even if the result is through UB). I surely expect these semantics where it *is* defined behavior (e.g. in Java or C#).

Comment: In most cases integer will just overflow if it cannot hold larger number.